# Custom gallery displayin and sorting error

Tags: uploads, metabox, gallery

I am making frontand gallery uploader. Here is my example code:

```
<?php 
    //start of "for" loop
    $attach_id = media_handle_upload($key, $post_id);
    $attach_ids[] = $attach_id;
    add_post_meta($post_id, 'user_submit_image', wp_get_attachment_url($attach_id));
    //end of "for" loop
?>
```

And i am trying display them in admin post edit page with metabox.

```
<?php
function gallery_meta_callback($post) {
    wp_nonce_field(basename(__FILE__), 'gallery_meta_nonce');
    $ids = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'user_submit_image');

    ?>
    <table class="form-table">
      <tr><td>
        <a class="gallery-add button" href="#">Add Image(s)</a>

        <ul id="gallery-metabox-list">
        <?php if ($ids): foreach ($ids as $key => $value): $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src($value);?>

                  <li>
                    <input type="hidden" name="user_submit_image[<?php echo $key; ?>]" value="<?php echo $value; ?>">
                    <img class="image-preview" src="<?php echo $image[0]; ?>">
                    <a class="change-image" href="#" >Change Image</a><br>
                    <a class="remove-image" href="#">Remove Image</a>
                  </li>

                <?php endforeach;endif;?>
        </ul>

      </td></tr>
    </table>
  <?php }

function gallery_meta_save($post_id) {
    if (isset($_POST['user_submit_image'])) {
        update_post_meta($post_id, 'user_submit_image', $_POST['user_submit_image']);
    } else {
        delete_post_meta($post_id, 'user_submit_image');
    }
}
add_action('save_post', 'gallery_meta_save');
?>
```

And i must display on frontend:

```
<div class="gallery">
    <?php 
    $ids = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'user_submit_image');
    foreach ($ids as $key => $value) : $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src($value); ?>
        <div class="item">
        <img src="<?php echo $image[0]; ?>">
        </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>                                                                        
</div>
```

But i cat do it :) Where do i make mistakes?

Comment: In `add_post_meta()` you're saving a URL, but in `get_post_meta()` you're treating the values as IDs.

Comment: i edited **<img class="image-preview" src="<?php echo $value; ?>">** and it sorting images. Problem is when i try update_post_meta, it updates value as **array()**